# Join Array elements

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

i want to join array elements into string..

i have this code

```
Dim qry(3) As String
    Dim text As String
    If (TextBox1.Text <> String.Empty) Then
        qry(0) = "f_name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
    End If
    If (TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty) Then
        qry(1) = "m_name = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
    End If
    If (TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty) Then
        qry(2) = "l_name = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'"
    End If

    text = String.Join(" AND ", qry)

    MsgBox(text)
```

which join Array like this

> f_name = 'XYZ' AND m_name = 'PQR' AND l_name = 'ABC' AND

but i want string like this

> f_name = 'XYZ' AND m_name = 'PQR' AND l_name = 'ABC'

Comment: Maybe it would be easiest to take from resut string substring() without last 4 characters. text = text.Substring(text.Length - 4)

Comment: The only reason you are getting 3 ANDs is that you declared the `qry` array to have 4 elements (even though you are not assigning a value to the 4th. In VB, you specify the highest index, not the number of elements when declaring an array, so your first statement should be `Dim qry(2) As String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a generic List instead of static array:

```
Dim arrFilters As List<String>
Dim text As String
If (TextBox1.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    arrFilters.Add("f_name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'")
End If
If (TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    arrFilters.Add("m_name = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'")
End If
If (TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    arrFilters.Add("l_name = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'")
End If

text = String.Join(" AND ", arrFilters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `string.Join()` try building your qry in your own loop:

```
Dim qryTxt As string = string.Empty

For i As integer = 0 To qry.GetUpperBound(0) 
    If qryTxt = string.Empty() Then
        qryTxt = qry(i)
    Else
        qryTxt = qryTxt + " AND " + qry(i)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the concatenation with + and & .
Use System.Text.StringBuilder. It is much faster (I did once a programm to export a db in query instructions and with concatenation It took some minutes, with StringBuilder less than 5 seconds).
So your code should be :

```
  Dim sb As new system.Text.StringBuilder
If (TextBox1.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    sb.Append("f_name = '")  
    sb.Append(TextBox1.Text) 
    sb.Append("'")   
End If
If (TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    if sb.Length>0 then sb.Append(" AND ")
    sb.Append("m_name = '")  
    sb.Append(TextBox2.Text) 
    sb.Append("'")  
End If
If (TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty) Then
    if sb.Length>0 then sb.Append(" AND ")
    sb.Append("l_name = '")  
    sb.Append(TextBox3.Text) 
    sb.Append("'") 
End If
MsgBox(sb.ToString)
```

Supposed that you do not need the array of values in some other place. It would not justify to handle twice. If you need the array, you could usee String.Concat(st1,st2,st3...) it gives also a good performance. And than loop